# Correctly set Visual Studio linker flag /SUBSYSTEM in CMAKE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, cmake

I am trying to set up an old project using cmake and I would like to keep all flags the same as before. 
The old project generator has the linker flag `/SUBSYSTEM` with minimum subystem version number `5.01` set like this:

```
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,"5.01"
```

I tried the same in cmake by adding this:

```
set_target_properties(mytarget PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,\"5.01\"")
```

However the result is wrong. Cmake seems to remove the (escaped) double quotes and places the linker flag to "Addition Options" in the Visual Studio project: `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01`

This way the subsystem flag is not recognized and set to `CONSOLE`.

I tried several combinations how to add the min version `,"5.01"` to the subsystem flag but without success.

Is there any other way to add the minimum subsystem version number to the /SUBSYSTEM flag?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: My Visual Studio version is 2012, but it should also work for 2003 since this my release compiler.

Comment: Have you tried *double-escaping*: `\\\"5.01\\\"`. Some times ago I have seen mailing about strange escaping rules for some properties, when proper escaping depends even from generator in use.

Comment: I tried that too, the result was `\"5.01\"`. Anyway, thank you for your comment. I am now using `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` without the min version since it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 42):

You can simply use the `[WIN32]` flag in the [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html) function :

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 9):

Long time to answer but I have found a solution:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

Comment: This answer is invalid when `${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}` string contains `/subsystem:console`. Better use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57645234/4927212) provided by [@Zouch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4717805/).