# Setting linker subsystem with CMake and clang++ in windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clang++

I'm trying to make a windowed application with SDL in windows, using ninja to build. When I try to build, I get the error:

```
lld-link: error: subsystem must be defined
```

It seems I need to set the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` linker flag for it to work. How can I set that in CMake?

I tried using the `WIN32` flag mentioned in [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html), but the clang command doesn't change when I try to build again, and the error still happens.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553436/building-with-cmake-ninja-and-clang-on-windows) too, even though it seems to refer to a different issue, but it didn't help.
I also tried the other answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873735/correctly-set-visual-studio-linker-flag-subsystem-in-cmake), adding

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

but it just throws `no such file or directory: '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use

```
target_link_options(your_target_name PRIVATE "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

See cmake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_options.html